# Get data from an insert query?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I know you can get the insert id of a query with:

```
$query->id
```

But is there a way to get data back out from the query?

For example, I wish to return what was inserted back to the user and output it on my page. If I just return the data that is sent for insertion then it will not been sanitized and could cause problems.

Is there a way to do this?

Or will I need to do another query or perhaps just manually sanities the data?

Comment: How about loading the content again from the DB and return it? You have the last inserted id so it isn't that difficult.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? What does `$query` contain?

Answer (score 0):

Databases don't return the data that was inserted; they return a status indicating whether it was successfully inserted or not. So you can't get the data back out from your `$query`.

That said... you just inserted the data! You've already got access to it in your program. Depending on what you need, that might be enough. Or it might not - if your program *needs* auto-generated timestamps, data produced from database triggers, or other information from the database then you'll have to use another query. But if you're after the data you inserted, plus its ID, you've already got that in your program and don't have to perform another DB query.

Comment: Thanks, but I should sanitise the data before outputting to the view - correct?

Comment: It depends. If you're storing sanitised data in your database, then yes. If not: your view should already be presuming that the data passed in is insanitary, and doing the sanitisation itself.

Comment: I can do this in the view with triple brackets: {{{ $var }}}?

Comment: Yep, if you're using [Blade templating](http://laravel.com/docs/templates), triple-curly-brackets will escape it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you are sanitizing your data. If you are using Accessors and Mutators - then when you add the information to the object - it is already sanitizied.

So if you have the follow mutator or accessor (up to you which you use)

```
 class User extends Eloquent {

    public function getNameAttribute($value)
    {
        return ucwords($value);
    }

}
```

Then it results in this:

```
   $user->name = "test name";
   echo $user->name;   // "Test Name"
```

But if you do some other kind of logic it might not be the same.

Comment: So, if I did: $user = new User;

$user->name = 'John';

$user->save();
Then I did something with $user->name, that value would be sanitised?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "sanitised". But any mutation/accessor is applied to the object